# Single Board Computer for Real-Time Object Detection

Tags: camera, hardware, artificial-intelligence, jetson, object-detection

I am developing a pallet detection and pose estimation algorithm with YOLOv3, using a depth camera - R435.

Since real time classification is a burden on hardware, I am looking for something that is capable of doing what I need.

One of my colleagues said that **NVIDIA Jetson** might not be "enough" for doing such a task. I've been recommended to use mini PCs like **Intel Nuc**.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I have used Intel NUC and for my application, it worked well. Disabling the GUI should also help a lot. Here are some other boards that I found: https://www.electromaker.io/blog/article/best-sbc-for-ai-single-board-computer-for-artificial-intelligence

Comment: @you_know_who thanks. Then I'll try using it headless too. Just one thing, do you remember which model was yours specifically? Because their GPUs change model to model and I wonder how big of a performance difference is there, for a computer vision task.

Comment: I don't remember exactly. But it was sometime August/Sept 2022 when it was purchased. I guess it was the latest at that time. But its a good idea to see performance comparison before making a purchase. Newer/ higher price model don't always translate to higher performance.